# Vue Js - Calculation Criteria in Reverse

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Am Having situation where i had to reverse a calculation criteria to make it clear  :

1. i have sub_total field which is editable and user can change the value of it
2. first the pre tax is applied to this sub_total and give me pre_total
3. second the vato tax is applied to the sum of ( sub_total and pre_total ) and give me vato_total
4. third the tx tax is applied to the sub_total and give me tx_total
5. the final step is the grand total which is the sum of sub_total + pre_total + vato_total + tx_total  .

and here is the demonstration code of the above steps :

```
let subtotal_with_ewa = Number((this.subtotal_price / 100) * this.unit.reservation.prices.ewa_parentage) + Number(this.subtotal_price);
            this.total_ewa = parseFloat((this.subtotal_price / 100) * this.unit.reservation.prices.ewa_parentage).toFixed(2)
            this.total_vat = parseFloat((subtotal_with_ewa / 100 ) * this.unit.reservation.prices.vat_parentage).toFixed(2);
            this.total_ttx = parseFloat((this.subtotal_price / 100) * this.unit.reservation.prices.tourism_percentage).toFixed(2);
            this.total_price = parseFloat(subtotal_with_ewa + Number(this.total_vat) + Number(this.total_tourism)).toFixed(2);
            this.unit.reservation.prices.total_price_raw = parseFloat(subtotal_with_ewa + Number(this.total_vat) + Number(this.total_ttx) ).toFixed(2);
            this.unit.reservation.prices.total_price = this.unit.reservation.prices.total_price_raw ;
            this.total_price = this.unit.reservation.prices.total_price ;
            this.unit.reservation.prices.price = this.subtotal_price
```

and it's working perfect as the following screen shot
[image]

now the question is : what do i do to make the whole operation as reverse i mean what i had to do if i changed the grand total value i need to re-calcuate those values till get the sub_total again .... any ideas ?

Comment: Pre, Vato and Tx fields are not editable right?

Comment: yes , they calculated on the fly

Comment: set Subtotal -> calc Total, set Total -> calc Subtotal ?

Comment: @Estradiaz , the issue i have here is that ( pre & tx taxes ) are applied to the sub_total but ( vato tax ) applied to the sub_total + pre_total only so there no way clear to me to fetch the value of tx_total

Answer (score 0):

You need to make computed properties they will recompute any time a dependancy is changed, for example:

```
subtotal_with_ewa(){
     return Number((this.subtotal_price / 100) * 
     this.unit.reservation.prices.ewa_parentage) + Number(this.subtotal_price);
    }
```

You can use getters and setters with computed properties or separate them from the bound v-model on the fields.

Answer (score 0):

The below functions should solve the problem.

the function accepts the percentage of each tax as argument and returns a json will all the values.

```js
function fromSubTotal(subTotal, pre, vato, tx) {
    const preAmount = subTotal * pre / 100
    const vatoAmount = (subTotal + pre) * vato / 100
    const txAmount = subTotal * tx / 100
    const total = subTotal + preAmount + vatoAmount + txAmount
    return {subTotal, preAmount, vatoAmount, txAmount, total}
}

function fromTotal(total, pre, vato, tx) {
    const subTotal = (total * 100) / (100 + pre + tx + (1.01 * pre * vato))
    return fromSubTotal(subTotal, pre, vato, tx)
}

// eg.
console.log(fromSubTotal(100,1,1,1))
console.log(fromTotal(103.01,1,1,1))
```